# After updating the Cypress 3.1.2 version failed to open the Cypress app

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I have updated Cypress version from `3.1.0 to 3.1.2` by running the following command `npm install --save-dev cypress@3.1.2`. After that, I have cd to my Tests folder and try to run the following command `C:\Project\Tests>C:\node_modules\.bin\cypress open`, getting below error. Did someone try updating to latest version and encountered the same problem ? This was working perfectly fine in 3.1.0

```
module.js:471
    throw err;    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\node_modules\cypress\bin\cypress'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:505:3
```

Comment: just try adding `"open": "cypress open"` to your npm scripts

Comment: where do I need to add the `"open": "cypress open" ` , can you please provide the location of that file ?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

Comment: Unable to open the Cypress app

Comment: post your entire `package.json` config

Comment: uninstall cypress globally, delete your node modules folder, reinstall, try again

Comment: I have also got selenium-cucumber.js  using the node modules, so if delete node modules folder I may loose the respective files related to cucumber.js tests

Comment: deleting node modules should never have any affect on your application code

Comment: ***Error: Cannot find module 'C:\node_modules\cypress\bin\cypress'*** indicates the install happened in the C drive root, not your project folder. Perhaps you should cd to Tests folder first ***then*** install Cypress?